# Python Subprocess.Run() outputcontrol

Tags: python, subprocess, output, stdout

Hellow exports.

I am new to python. and to explain my problem I simply the script.

I built 2 python files.  The first one is like the below file name is "random.py"

```
p1 =[1,2,'bob']
p2 =[1,2,'eric']
p3 =[2,1,'dimitar']
p4 =[2,2,'kyle']

l1 = [p1,p2,p3,p4]

print(l1)
```

and the result will be like this : (double list)

[[1, 2, 'bob'], [1, 2, 'eric'], [2, 1, 'dimitar'], [2, 2, 'kyle']]

The Second file is for running the first python file. using Run() function.

```
import subprocess
res = subprocess.run("python random.py", shell=True,capture_output=True )
print(res.stdout)
```

and the result will be like this :

b"[[1, 2, 'bob'], [1, 2, 'eric'], [2, 1, 'dimitar'], [2, 2, 'kyle']]\r\n"

My question is that how I can to get Result same as first result (and if it's possible, I just want to get double List but not string)

My basic idea is to run some program and get the output it creates.  in this case, I run the first python file. and get output(l1) from the Second python file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import subprocess
import ast
res = subprocess.run("python random.py", shell=True, capture_output=True)
k = res.stdout.decode()
newlist = ast.literal_eval(k)
print(newlist)
print(type(newlist))
```

you can try to use this code.
[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the output of `random.py` for anything else, it's best to use an encoding mechanism rather than relying on the python str/repr conversions. JSON works well, like so:

```
import json
...
json.dump(sys.stdout, l1)
```

Then in the runner file, load the json from the bytes:

```
import json
...
print(json.loads(res.stdout))
```

Comment: Interesting.  Thank you for the information. I needed run() function for control input and output. Anyway, thank you for the commendt. It help my python study.  I will look json as well but for now, Mayank gives me the solution.

Comment: Yes, my suggestion is to decode the output of `run`. I just omitted the unchanging code. Perhaps next time I'll paste the whole suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without using `subprocess`. You are able to `import` the first file into the second.

The first thing to do in the first file is to change it so that the code you want to use is a function. And that it return the value you want.

If you still want to call the first file from the command line you can use Python's `if __name__ == "__main__":` check to only run certain command if it is called from the command line.

There is more about this at:

https://www.pythonmorsels.com/making-main-function-python/

So your first file could look something like this and still perform the same as before:

`so_74917104_a.py`

```py
def random():
    p1 = [1, 2, "bob"]
    p2 = [1, 2, "eric"]
    p3 = [2, 1, "dimitar"]
    p4 = [2, 2, "kyle"]

    l1 = [p1, p2, p3, p4]
    return l1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(random())
```

Your second file would not use `subprocess` but `import` the first file. E.g.

`so_74917104_b.py`

```py
import so_74917104_a


def main():
    double_list = so_74917104_a.random()
    print("data is of type:", type(double_list))
    print("data contents are:", double_list)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which give the output:

```
data is of type: <class 'list'>
data contents are: [[1, 2, 'bob'], [1, 2, 'eric'], [2, 1, 'dimitar'], [2, 2, 'kyle']]
```

I have not called the first file `random.py` to ensure that you can still load the [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module with `import random` rather than your file. You can give your second file a more meaningful name but just be careful about clashing with other modules.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. But I still needed to use run() function because I using input control as well. Anyway thank you so much.